# Postfix Setup for Action Mailbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I followed the instructions from the offical Ruby on Rails Guide. I can run a script on incoming mail.

But I have no clue how to invoke the action_mailbox:ingress:postfix command. 
Somehow I have to switch into the workspace and then run bin/rails. 
Is there some best practice for sending the mail to rails?

Comment: Hey Johnathan, can you post how you solved this and help other developers like myself struggling to configure the postfix with action mailbox? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the steps to configure postfix with action mailbox in production server:

Step 1: Create bash script

Create a script inside `/usr/local/bin/` to forward all incoming emails to our rails app:

`$ nano email_forwarder.sh`

Add following to the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export HOME=YOUR_HOME_PATH
export PATH=YOUR_PATH
export RBENV_ROOT=YOUR_RBENV_PATH

cd /path/to/your/project && bin/rails action_mailbox:ingress:postfix URL='https://truemark.com.np/rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails' INGRESS_PASSWORD='YOUR_INGRESS_PASSWORD'
```

Replace value of `HOME`, `PATH`, `RBENV_ROOT`, `URL` and `INGRESS_PASSWORD` as described below:

- Copy your home directory for `HOME`

```
$ cd
$ pwd
```

- Copy what you get from $PATH and which rbenv command for PATH and RBENV_PATH respectively

```
$ $PATH
$ which rbenv
```

- Copy the password you added to `credentials` or your `ENV` / `application.yml` file for `INGRESS_PASSWORD`
- For URL, if your application lived at https://example.com, the full command would look like this:

```
bin/rails action_mailbox:ingress:postfix URL='https://example.com/rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails' INGRESS_PASSWORD='YOUR_STRONG_PASSWORD'
```

Step 2: Configure Postfix to Pipe Incoming emails to script

- Create `/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases` to add a catch-all alias; localuser needs to be an existing local user:

```
# /etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
@mydomain.tld   localuser@mydomain.tld
```

- Create `/etc/postfix/transport` to add a transport mapping. **forward_to_rails** can be whatever you want; it will be used later in `master.cf`

```
# /etc/postfix/transport
mydomain.tld    forward_to_rails:
```

- Next, both `transport` and `virtual_aliases` need to be compiled into berkeley db files:

```
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

- Add the transport to `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

```
# /etc/postfix/master.cf
forward_to_rails   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Xhq user=deploy:deploy argv=/usr/local/bin/email_forwarder.sh
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

We should specify user so script is run by that user and not postfix or nobody. `user=deploy:deploy` ~ `user=user:group`

- Add following in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf
  transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
  virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_aliases
```

You can view postfix log with `tail -f /var/log/mail.log`.

And done! You should be able to receive the email now in you action mailbox.

You can read about the solution in detail here: https://thedevpost.com/blog/setup-action-mailbox-with-postfix-part-2/

For setting up action mailbox and testing in development, you can read about it in detail here: https://thedevpost.com/blog/setup-action-mailbox-with-postfix-part-1/

Comment: Can you summarize your findings here? Providing a link for more information is fine, but your answer should stand alone without it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html#postfix):

> [Configure Postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/258469/how-to-configure-postfix-to-pipe-all-incoming-email-to-a-script) to pipe inbound emails to `bin/rails action_mailbox:ingress:postfix`, providing the `URL` of the Postfix ingress and the `INGRESS_PASSWORD` you previously generated. If your application lived at `https://example.com`, the full command would look like this:
>   `$ bin/rails action_mailbox:ingress:postfix URL=https://example.com/rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails INGRESS_PASSWORD=...`

So postfix is the one running that command

Comment: I tell postfix which user to use. That works fine but I can run this rails command only from the rails application folder (if I am correct). So I tried to switch the folder but it failed. I wonder if I can not have a ruby script sending the mail that does not need the whole rails app.

Comment: Did you tell postfix how to run the script? It should be something like `mailbox_command = /path/to/my/script.sh` and inside that script put something like `bin/rails action_mailbox:ingress:postfix URL=https://example.com/rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails INGRESS_PASSWORD=...`, that script could live in your rails app folder if that's what you need

Comment: I tried to call bin/rails directly and it fails because of missing rake-file. I will try to add a script. Anyhow it is annoying that I need to have the rails app on my mail server. When I use a script I fear to loose the mail body and I am not sure how I am supposed to pass it.

Comment: You don't need to have your app on your email server but you need to have a postfix instance configured on the same server as your app and then relay to it from your principal email server. On the one that is running together with your app you need to configure the mailbox script. For the missing rake file try something like `cd /path/to/your/app && rails action_mailbox ...`

Comment: I can not use cd as its executed by execvp. Anyhow the postfix manual (http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) teached me that I can give the working directory as a parameter. Next problem I can not use ruby command as I user rvm and the profile is not loaded. So I called bin/rails via ruby: `/path/to/rvm/ruby bin/rails`. That seems to work but for some reason its missing the gems now :-/

Comment: It works now using rvm wrappers. Will add an answer later. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JonathanHeinen if you could elaborate on how you got it set up in the end that would be much appreciated!

Comment: One part I don't quite get is why I need to add the full URL to the command. Does that mean that the app processing the inbound email does not need to run on the same server? All you need is some skeleton rails app with ActionMailbox and it will send the message across the network to a different server?!

Comment: @JonathanHeinen it would be great if you can share a good answer on how you configured everything! The documentation on the Rails site it's quite confusing :(

Comment: @JonathanHeinen What is the "ingress password" how do I configure that on Postfix? and the "https://example.com" would be my localhost host right?

Comment: Hey @JonathanHeine, I am going to try to post a working example later, for now just check the docs, the password can be added to your application's encrypted credentials under `action_mailbox.ingress_password`, where Action Mailbox will automatically find it or just use the `RAILS_INBOUND_EMAIL_PASSWORD` env variable. (from https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html#postfix)

Comment: @JonathanHeinen could you please share what you did with rvm wrappers, I am using rbenv and having similar issue to yours, 
profile is not loaded hence it is using system ruby and causing ruby version conflict